# Varscoper for CFScript based components

Tags: coldfusion, cfc

As we all know, varScoping your ColdFusion code is an absolute must for any non-trivial project.

CF9 brings many enhancements to CFScript, such as being able to write entire CFC's in script, including component, function and property tags.

However varScoper won't work with cfScript defined functions/components. It just doesn't attempt to check functions declared in script.

The question is, what is everyone using for varscoping their cfScript based CFC's?

dave

Comment: Oooh, interesting question. I suspect the unfortunate answer is "they're not doing it". :/ I certainly haven't seen any mention of any tools other than varscoper, and as you say that doesn't handle it (and updating it so it does is non-trivial).

Comment: I guess it is much more complex task than processing good old CFML. For example, CFEclipse team having troubles with reliable CFScript parsing for years.

Comment: Sergii, considering how good Builder is as parsing everything (eg control-click & autocomplete) i'm surprised Adobe hasn't included it in builder.

Answer (score 1):

VarScope is under an Apache licence, so is "open source".  You could always touch base with the bloke in charge of it and see if he'd be interested in third-party updates to it, and perhaps you could make the changes yourself?  It would certainly earn you community brownie points!

Not an entirely satisafactory answer, I know.

To answer your actual question: until CF has full CFScript coverage for the functionality we use (or are likely to want to use) in CFCs we won't implement any script-only CFCs.  And for our tag-based ones we just use a tight coding standard and have code peer review before committing anything for release.  Occasionally we run varscoper, but it does a less good job of finding problems than two sets of eyes do: varscoper does seem to come up with a lot of false positives.

Another consideration is that if you have 100% unit test coverage (yes, I know: who does?) then checking what's in the variables scope of a CFC after you've run your tests will show up any leaks into the variables scope.

Comment: It's possible to change your code to not false-positive with varscoper.  The biggest change we had to make was in named params in script, instead of name=value, we used name:value.  The name:value syntax still works with CF.   We found worthwhile, and getting 0 unscoped vars in the var scoper report is a critical part of the deployment build cycle.  Obviously each dev shop is different, we don't have peer review of all code.

Comment: Dave, I'm sure you're right. Anyone can fine-tune anything to sing a song not intended by the initial composer.  I'm not dissin' the tool, I'm just giving props to human eyeballs: in my exposure to varscoper, eyeballs are more accurate than automation.  FWIW, I'm not talking about any esoteric CF9 or CF8 or even CFMX7 code... just vanilla *code*: varscoper gives more false-positives than an attentive human does.  I'm probably lucky that I always have a spare set of eyeballs.